# Text box not getting reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a text box and I tried to reset it after a button click. But it is not getting reset.
HTML Script:-

```
    <input type="text" name="" class="input-default" id="inp">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-b-10 m-l-5" onclick="add()">Add</button>
<select id='pre-selected-options' multiple='multiple'>
    <option value='elem_1' selected>1</option>
    <option value='elem_2'>a</option>
    <option value='elem_3'>x</option>
    <option value='elem_4' selected>Ce</option>
    <option value='elem_100'>Td</option>
  </select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
```

JavaScript Code :-

```
var x;
var option;
var y;

function add() {
    var x = document.getElementById('pre-selected-options');
    console.log(x);
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = document.getElementById("inp").value;
    var y = option.text
    x.add(option);
    $('#pre-selected-options').multiSelect('addOption', {
        value: y,
        text: y,
        index: 0,
        nested: 'optgroup_label'
    });
    document.getElementById('pre-selected-options').reset();
}

$('#pre-selected-options').multiSelect();
```

I tried adding this and its not resetting the form :

```
document.getElementById('pre-selected-options').reset();
```

Comment: Reset in your context means clear the value?

Comment: yes clearing the text box

Comment: Please add full html including `pre-selected-options` id element.

Comment: You can simply use `document.getElementById('pre-selected-options').value = ""`  to clear the value

Comment: Yes, please provide at least a minimal working example. Otherwise its hard to help you

Comment: I'm curious why you use JavaScript meanwhile you have jQuery in your code...

Comment: document.getElementById('pre-selected-options').value = "" I tried this and there is no effect

Comment: Wait, your question states `text box` but your code makes me believe you are using a `dropdown`. Are you trying to clear a dropdown or a textbox?

Comment: Codeer, the first line of html have the input box code

Comment: Then you need to use `document.getElementById('inp').value = ""`

Comment: Use Jquery... $("#inp").val("");

Comment: Codeer that worked..how foolish I am...

Comment: Don't worry. I also added it as an answer so it is more visible to other users visiting this question

Comment: thats nice nyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble you are facing here is that you are trying to clear the input box with id `inp` while calling `pre-selected-options`, which isn't connected to your text box.

Using `document.getElementById('inp').value = ""` should clear the value of your textbox.

Answer (score 4):

To reset a form, use

```
form.reset();
```

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  form.reset();
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input value="volvo">

  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button">Reset form</button>
</form>
```

---

To reset a value on e.g. `input`, use

```
input.value = '';
```

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = '';
})
```

```html
<input value="volvo">


<button>Reset to none</button>
```

---

To reset a value on e.g. `select`, use

```
select.selectedIndex = 0;    // select first option
select.selectedIndex = -1;   // select none
```

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  select.selectedIndex = -1;   // select none
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<button>Reset Select to none</button>
```

Comment: not on select .... reset value in this :<input type="text" name="" class="input-default" id="inp">

Comment: I nowhere said that i need to reset select.. But this is a good answer I will post a question for the same and will let you know

Comment: @qwww My bad, but you do refer to the `select` with `document.getElementById('pre-selected-options').reset();`, but then use `.reset()` on it, which is for `form`, .... and in your question there is no attempt to reset an `input`, but you mention you tried to reset the `form` with it, so it all becomes somewhat unclear to what is really asked for.

Comment: @qwww And no need for a second question, as if this answers that, it will be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value of input box use :

```
  document.getElementById('pre-selected-options').value = "";
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_clear_input.asp

Answer (score 0):

To reset form by using jQuery.

```
$("form")[0].reset();
```